# is there any way to prefix 00 before integer in xampp database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert zero before integer value in my xampp database but it is not working. Is there any way to do it. 
I am developing a shopping website, so i just need 2 zero's before my price value in database. I have tried by putting 00 before my price value, it is showing 0 rows effected.

Comment: In PHP `echo "00".$price;`

Comment: Why would you want to do this? integers are numbers, how you're formatting them is not related to how you store them.

Comment: SELECT LPAD(my_column,2,0) FROM my_table; or something like that

Comment: You have to change your integer field to character/string if you want to add 00 at the start in your database.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the field type from **INT to Decimal** and **length/Values** to **11,2**. In this case 2 will be working as a decimal points for you. so whatever value you insert will be converted to 2 decimal points like 0.00 or 123.00

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it easier to enable Zero_Filling for the desired field in your database?
if you have a field which can contain 4 characters $7 will become 0007 and $345 will become 0345

Comment: @Azreal: To think you cannot do this on integer field. You will need character field only to do this type of conversion

Comment: This is possible on a integer field.

Comment: Yes it is, its an attribute called UNSIGNED ZEROFILL, I'm using it very often.